# Import sourceforge projects

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, profile-page

I can't add my sourceforge project to my profile page. I just receive the following message:

```
Sorry, we couldn't locate that user on SourceForge. Double check and try again?
```

I copied the URL of my sourceforge user from the browser as advised so I'm pretty sure the URL is correct.

Comment: are you still seeing this problem?

Comment: @Max yes: "Leider konnten wir diesen Benutzer auf SourceForge nicht finden. Möchten Sie die Eingabe überprüfen und es erneut versuchen?"

Comment: Could you share the URL of your sourceforge user? I'm trying to repro this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to enter only your SourceForge user name, not the entire URL:

[image]